# Рисование n - конечной звезды с помощью Tkinter canvas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как нарисовать n-конечную звезду в Python, не используя Turtle?
Координаты вершин правильного n-угольника с центром в 0 - cos⁡(2πk/n),sin⁡(2πk/n), где k=1...n

Попытался сделать это:

```
import tkinter
import math
master = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master, bg='white', height=600, width=600)

n = int(input())
if n % 2 == 0:
    for k in range(n):
        k1 = (k + n / 2 - 1) % n
        p1 = (math.cos(2 * 3.14 * k // n), math.sin(2 * 3.14 * k // n))
        p2 = (math.cos(2 * 3.14 * k1 // n), math.sin(2 * 3.14 * k1 // n))
        canvas.create_line(p1, p2, fill = 'red')
else:
    for k in range(n):
        k1 = (k + (n - 1) / 2) % n
        p1 = (math.cos(2 * 3.14 * k // n), math.sin(2 * 3.14 * k // n))
        p2 = (math.cos(2 * 3.14 * k1 // n), math.sin(2 * 3.14 * k1 // n))
        canvas.create_line(p1, p2, fill = 'red')    
canvas.pack()
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: В чем конкретно сложность? Создаете canvas, на нем рисуете с помощью create_line.

Comment: Сложность в правильном порядке точек

Comment: Следующая точка должна быть от предыдущей чуть меньше чем на полоборота. Если `k=0...(n-1)`, то `k1=(k+n/2-1)%n` для четных n или `k1=(k+(n-1)/2)%n` для нечетных.

Comment: Для n=7, например, возможно две звезды...

Comment: @insolor Добавил в вопрос то, что сделал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формула из вопроса дает координаты относительно нуля и в диапазоне от -1 до 1. Нужно домножить результат на величину радиуса и сдвинуть координаты на середину холста. И еще, в формуле должно использоваться обычное деление вместо целочисленного, иначе звезда будет искажена.

Исправленный код:

```
import tkinter
import math
master = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master, bg='white', height=600, width=600)
canvas.pack()

r = 100

n = int(input('Количество лучей:'))

for k in range(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        k1 = (k + n / 2 - 1) % n
    else:
        k1 = (k + (n - 1) / 2) % n

    p1 = (300 + r * math.cos(2 * 3.14 * k / n), 300 + r * math.sin(2 * 3.14 * k / n))
    p2 = (300 + r * math.cos(2 * 3.14 * k1 / n), 300 + r * math.sin(2 * 3.14 * k1 / n))
    canvas.create_line(p1, p2, fill = 'red')

master.mainloop()
```